# Is voltage varying in function of current or the other way around?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

I'm confused by Ohm's formula which I meet often. 
I intuitively think that current is the dependant variable and voltage is the independant variable, but every body writes v=ri which suggest the contrary.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here. The question is clearly not asked by an experienced physicist, but we are here to help people with physics. The question itself is interesting and we can help answer it using physics. I, for one, am glad that questions like this are asked.

Comment: @BobKnighton, a hover over the downvote button brings up hover text that includes "This question does not show any research effort..." and so the downvotes might be because the question doesn't show any research effort.  A quick search brought up this at the SE EE site:  [Does voltage cause current or does current cause voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201533/does-voltage-cause-current-or-does-current-cause-voltage) along with others such as [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/ohms-law-why-current-induces-electric-field-and-cause-effect-direction.413407/)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - either way.

There are different sources of energy in an electrical circuit; among them are current sources and voltage sources.

When you have a voltage source (like a battery) and you apply it across a resistor, current will start to flow in accordance with $I = \frac{V}{R}$.

If you have a current source and you apply it across a resistor, a voltage will be developed: $V = I\times R$.

Now I sometimes find it helpful to think of the second case as "a bunch of electrons try to squeeze through a wire, but they can't all do it at once because of resistance; so they end up piling up at one end, until the pile is big enough that their pressure forces them through the wire". That's terribly hand-wavy, but it may be helpful if you're confused. Similarly, if the voltage you apply is fixed, current will start to flow until the rate at which it flows (the "pressure" needed to go through the wire depends on the number of electrons flowing per second) is just right for the voltage applied.

Does that help?

Comment: I understand you can't make a current appear without the presence of an electric field that moves it along. The concept of voltage only makes sense in an electric field, just like the concept of potential only makes sense in a conservative vector field. Hence the voltage is what is generating the current, it is difficult to think of a current generating voltage. Rather I'd see this as a current through a certain resistor can only be created by voltage V, and voltage V across a certain resistor can only generate a current I.

Comment: @Steve if you shoot an electron beam through a field free region at a poor conductor you will see that current can generate voltage...

Answer (score 1):

The correct description of which I'm aware of is that, current is a function of voltage, i.e., current is proportional to the voltage(potential diference).
 I ∝ V
 I = VC (where C is equal to conductance, which is reciprocal of resistance)
 I = V/R
which gives us ohm's law, V = IR.